# How to clear a model when my AngularFire app loads initially?

Tags: angularjs, angularfire

I am new to AngularFire and am trying to understand a simple concept.  If you go through the AngularFire tutorial located at the following url: http://angularfire.com/tutorial/index.html#gettingstarted there is a rudimentary example of using AngularFire to build a primitive "chat" application.

The tutorial is very clear and concise but I do not understand one primary point with it:

```
 function MyCtrl($scope, angularFire){
    $scope.messages = [];
    var ref = new Firebase("https://<xxxxxx>.firebaseio.com/messages");
    angularFire(ref, $scope, 'messages');
    $scope.messages = []; //shouldn't this clear the data locally and remotely?
 }
```

The issue is that a model is first created, and then the binding magic with AngularFire is setup such that there is now a 3-way binding to the model.  If there is an array of data already stored in Firebase, that data is fetched and synced and your model will now have this data locally.

What I simply do not understand is, when the controller code runs, suppose I set the model to an empty array AFTER the angularFire binding is wired up, why doesn't the Firebase data get cleared out?  Never mind the fact, that refreshing the page would basically keep wiping out the data (the behavior I want).

Now, I can get this behavior to work, if I wire up an ng-click event to a button, that calls a method named clear defined on my $scope object.  If within, that method, I simply call: $scope.messages = [];, then my model is cleared locally, and remotely.

But why doesn't this work on initialization?

Help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the remote data hasn't returned yet and is populated after your second call to $scope.messages =[]

edit:
Why not just explicitly remove your data from FB before binding it to a local list.

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<xxxxxx>.firebaseio.com/messages");
ref.remove();
```

Comment: I thought that too...however, if I wrap the second call in a setTimeout with say a 5 second delay, it still doesn't clear out my data.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found an answer to my own problem.  It looks like, you must wait until the promise returns to actually start modifying the model like so.  Now whenever I refresh my page, when my .then() runs, it will clear out my data.

I suppose this is how it should be done.  Can anyone confirm?

```
 $scope.messages = [];
 var ref = new Firebase("https://<xxxxxx>.firebaseio.com/items");
 var prom = angularFire(ref, $scope, 'messages');
 prom.then(function(){
     console.log("data loaded");
     $scope.messages = [];
 });
```